# iOS Read AppGroup from Entitlements programmatically in App and WatchKit Extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, continuous-integration, watchkit

Is there any way to read AppGroup from entitlements programatically.

I have achieved to read AppGroup programmatically but unable to get Entitlements file name programatically.  Can you suggest how to read value of `CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS` from build settings programmatically.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MY_APP_TARGET_NAME"
                                                 ofType:@"entitlements"];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSArray *appGroups = [dict objectForKey:@"com.apple.security.application-groups"];

for(NSString *appGroupValue in appGroups) {

    if([appGroupValue hasPrefix:@"group.com.xyz.myAppName"]) {
        appGroup = appGroupValue;
    }
}
```